# VBA ActiveX label in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have an ActiveX label in Excel with a value inside that corresponds to the value in Range("F4") as it updates. It is not in a form (a lot of the info on labels are on forms), but just on a regular worksheet. How can I make this happen?

I've been using this to assign label to macro but it's not working:

```
Sub CurrentPoints()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Label1.Value = Range("F4").Value
End Sub
```

The necessary calculations are already done and appear correctly in cell F4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to define and `Set` all my objects in my code.

First, set `Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `Sht` object (type `Worksheet`).

Second, set Label1 Active-X to `MyLbl`, object (type `OLEObject`).

At last, change the `Caption` of `MyLbl` object.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CurrentPoints()

Dim Sht  As Worksheet
Dim MyLbl As OLEObject

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' set the Active-X label object
Set MyLbl = Sht.OLEObjects("Label1")

' change the Caption to the value in Range "F4")
MyLbl.Object.Caption = Sht.Range("F4").Value

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: After client's notes, need to move the code to `Worksheet` module, and tie it to `Worksheet_Change` event.

***Modified Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyLbl As OLEObject

' check if the cell that was changed is "F4"
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4")) Is Nothing Then

    ' set the Active-X label object
    Set MyLbl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Label1")

    ' change the Caption to the value in Range "F4")
    MyLbl.Object.Caption = Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for your detailed explanation, I understand how labels work now. Here's what I did: I dragged a new label into the sheet, named it "Label1", used the code you typed for a new Sub and assigned the label to the macro. I'm sure the code is right but the label info still isn't changing, have I missed something when using the label?

Comment: @TaylorAndy it depends what you are trying to do with the code, do you want the label's caption to change whenever the value in "F4" changes ? or you want to press the Label to do so ?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I guess I should have specified, I'm such a noob T.T, I would like the label's caption to change whenever F4 changes. So if Range("F4").Value = 2, the label will show 2. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @TaylorAndy ok then, try the code under **Edit 1**, you need to copy it to the relevant worksheet module